# Parade floats - Copyright Infringement or Fair Use?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

In various countries in Europe, we have these parades in which floats drive around in a parade. These floats are sort of forms of art displayed to the public during a parade, thereafter often sold or destroyed. When sold this either happens fully or in separate pieces and then they are often recolored and edited due to maintenance and artistic choice.These aren't created for commercial intent but are made by groups of volunteers for cultural purposes.

Is it copyright infringement to recreate parts e.g. characters on these floats in digital work such as a commercial product under European law? If so, who should be asked for permission? Especially when some are over 20 years old and are sold to a new volunteer group of float creators each year.